# reducing space in the tikz-qtree package

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, linguistics, tikz-qtree

I have the following code to construct a tree using the  `tikz-qtree` package but the tree is too wide and also long. How can I fix it so that it reduces overall and is compact ?
Also, I am using `tikz-qtree` for the first time, so please excuse if it is a trivial question.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree,tikz-qtree-compat}
\begin{document}


 \begin{tikzpicture}
     \Tree 
     [.S
        [.NP   [.PRP \\It ] ]
        [ .VP
          [.VP  [ .VBZ\\ does ] [.RB \\not ]
            [.VP  [ .VB\\ seem ]
              [.S
                [.VP  [.TO\\ to ]
                  [.VP   [.VB\\ work ]
                    [.ADVP   [.RB\\ consistently   ] 
                    ] 
                    ] 
                    ] 
                    ] 
                    ] 
                    ]
          [.CC\\ and ]
          [.VP   [.VBZ\\ stops ]
            [.S
              [.VP  [.VBG\\ working  ]
                [.PP   [.IN\\ for  ] 
                  [.NP   [.DT\\ no ] [.NN\\ reason   
                   ] 
                   ] 
                   ] 
                   ] 
                   ] 
                   ] 
                   ]
         ] 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.  The simple answer to the question is to use the `forest` package instead, which was created to solve this kind of problem (i.e., packing tree nodes more compactly.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as suggest [Alan Munn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2693/alan-munn) in his comment above, with forest you can obtain more compact graph:

[image]

(red line show text border).

for use `forest` the changes of your code are small:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{forest}
%
      [S
        [NP   [PRP \\It ] ]
        [VP
          [VP    [VBZ\\ does ] [RB \\not,calign with current ]
            [VP    [VB\\ seem ]
              [S
                [VP  [TO\\ to ]
                  [VP   [VB\\ work ]
                    [ADVP   [RB\\ consistently   ]
                    ]
                    ]
                    ]
                    ]
                    ]
                    ]
          [CC\\ and,calign with current ]
          [VP   [VBZ\\ stops ]
            [S
              [VP  [VBG\\ working  ]
                [PP   [IN\\ for  ]
                  [NP   [DT\\ no ] [NN\\ reason
                   ]
                   ]
                   ]
                   ]
                   ]
                   ]
                   ]
         ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

**edit (1):** original answer is improved with considering [Alan Munn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2693/alan-munn)  comments: use `linguistic` option for forest which also make `for tree` superfluous.

**edit (2):** answer is further improved with [cfr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222/cfr) comment. with adding `calign with current` to the RB and CC nodes tree becomes neater. The same improvement is obtained by use of `calign with current edge`.

Comment: You need to remove all the `.`s from the code (which is `tikz-qtree` syntax) and also load `forest` with the `linguistics` option to get the labels and words to line up correctly.

Comment: @AlanMunn, thank you for suggestions. i'm not familiar with `tikz-qtree`, so i wrongly assume that dots are part of text. with `linguistics` option the tree becomes more "linguistic". i correct answer accordingly

Comment: You also don't need any of your `for tree` code.

Comment: @AlanMunn Perhaps I'm mistaken, but removing the dots has never been enough for me if I'm turning qtree syntax into forest syntax. Is tikz-qtree more forest-like?

Comment: @AlanMunn, indeed, i still learning `forest` ... and so far newer use `linguistic` option. thank you for your comment. it help me in my learning  very much!

Comment: @cfr The syntax of `tikz-qtree` and `qtree` are basically the same, but except for the manual spacing `!qsetw` type commands that `qtree` uses.  So removing the `.`s and loading the `linguistics` option usually suffices (although `tikz-qtree` allows `\node...` commands inside too and a few other things.)  So complex `tikz-qtree`s might need a bit of extra work. But simple `tikz-qtree` or `qtree` trees should be easy.

Comment: @AlanMunn The structures always change when I try it. Obviously I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: @cfr Ah, one more (important) detail I forgot: terminal nodes in `forest` must be bracketed, but don't need to be in `qtree` or `tikz-qtree`.  This probably accounts for why the structures change.  So it's not quite as seamless as I made it out to be.

Comment: @AlanMunn Ah, yes. That would be it. ;)

Comment: Try adding `calign with current` to the RB and CC nodes (or `calign with current edge`). I think it will look neater.

Comment: @cfr, thank you! considering your suggestion  tree really looks neater.